# Freewheel and quick release

Tags: freewheel, quick-release

I got myself a bike to fix up.  I changed the freewheel on it but I don't know how to position the nut after I put on the new freewheel.

If I screw it on too deep the chain will be too close to the frame so I am wondering if I am missing something.

The wheel is a quick release and I never worked with the quick release.  I tried to watch some YouTube videos but nothing really helped.

[image]

Comment: I wonder they mean the axle nuts?

Comment: @Criggie: I just wonder about the 'freewheel', could it be a cassette?

Comment: Does the chain actually get so close to the frame that it touches the frame?

Comment: Have you tried fitting this to the bike ?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely a freewheel, and a brand new one too.  I can only see the 6 sided axle nut, and no axle locknut.

Some designs have the cone nut buried deep inside the freewheel and then a spacer, and finally another nut on the outside, something like this:

[image]

Is it possible you replaced a 6 speed freewheel with a 7 speed freewheel, which is one cog wider?  This may require rebalancing the spacers on the axle.  You might be able to move a spacer from the left to the right side, and still have the required amount of axle body poking out.

Do note that a QR axle should end before it exits the frame - the QR's nut should be clamping on the frame not on the end of the axle.   If in doubt, get it checked over in person.

Comment: Hi criggie  Thank you for your reply  the original freewheel was a 7 speed  but was all rusty and I put it the way it was. I think I am missing something

Comment: @PatriceSouef did you remove or move the axle nut?  The chunky-looking six-sided one in the middle of the freewheel.   If not, then the chain should be fine on the new freewheel.

Comment: @PatriceSouef second thought - did you screw the freewheel onto the hub completely?  Did you put any kind of spacers behind it?

Comment: Yes the freewheel is put completely and I didn't put any spacers behind I put everything the way it was